# How to enter newline character in bookmarklet JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I try to write a bookmarklet which creates email, but there is an issue about using newline character.

When I execute the below code from Chrome Console, it works fine. However, this code doesn't work when executing from bookmarklet. I checked the code and the cause seems `var body1` includes newline character(`%0D%0A`).

Anybody knows how to insert newline character in bookmarklet JS?

```
javascript:(function(){
var today = new Date();
var url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm';
var to = 'emailfrombookmarklet@example.com';
var subject = '【weather%20report】【' + today.getFullYear() + '-' + ("00" + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ("00" + today.getDate()).slice(-2) + '%20bar】%20email%20from%20bookmarklet';
var body1 = 'Hi%2C%0D%0A%0D%0AThis is Kim Kardashian%2E%0D%0AIt%27s%20sunny%20today%2E%0D%0A%0D%0Adate%3A';
var targetDate = '%20' + today.getFullYear() + '-' + ("00" + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ("00" + today.getDate()).slice(-2);
var body2 = '%0D%0AName%3A%20Kim%20Kardashian%0D%0A';
var body3 = '%0D%0ABest%20Regards%2C';
url += '&to=' + to + '&su=' + subject + '&body=' + body1 + targetDate + body2 + body3;
window.open(url);})();
```

Comment: Try encoding the percent character itself.

Comment: @CBroe wow, I changed `%` to `%25`, then it works! thank you for the answer!

Comment: `%0D%0A` means `\r\n`.  In fact in might be better not to change `%` for `%25`, because it will work in a bookmark, but **will fail** in browser console. It is better to replace `%0A` for **`decodeURI('%250A')`**. So it will be `%0D+decodeURI('%250A')`. This will work everywhere! [extra info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76995249/5410914)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to get rid of using encoded characters at all:

```
javascript:(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm';
    var to = 'emailfrombookmarklet@example.com';
    var subject = '【weather report】【' + today.getFullYear() + '-' + ('00' + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('00' + today.getDate()).slice(-2) + ' bar】 email from bookmarklet';
    var body1 = 'Hi,\n\nThis is Kim Kardashian.\nIt\'s sunny today.\n\ndate:';
    var targetDate = ' ' + today.getFullYear() + '-' + ('00' + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('00' + today.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var body2 = '\nName: Kim Kardashian\n';
    var body3 = '\nBest Regards,';
    url += '&to=' + encodeURIComponent(to) + '&su=' + encodeURIComponent(subject) + '&body=' + encodeURIComponent(body1 + targetDate + body2 + body3);
    window.open(url);
})();
```