# JS-code with newline character `%0A` works in console, but fails as a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, async-await, bookmarklet

I am writing a bookmarklet, and I wish it works in browser console as well.

To make it easier to understand, the code makes an async API-call (imitates real; which is perfectly legit) to the server. It is supposed to change the message I clicked edit on, add "Text-1" at the beginning of the message, and save the message.

```
javascript:(async function(){
    var msgIdInChange = '';
    var targetNode = '';
    var textOfMsgInChange = '';
    var textToInsert = '';
    
    msgIdInChange = document.getElementsByClassName('editing-message')[0].getAttribute('msg-id'); /*getting msg-id of the actively editing message*/
    
    targetNode = document.querySelector("[node-id=" +CSS.escape(msgIdInChange)+ "]"); /*getting targetNode by msg-id from DOM*/
    textOfMsgInChange = targetNode.innerText;
    
    textToInsert = 'Text-1: ' + textOfMsgInChange;
    
    
    var currentChatId = '';
    var myToken = '';
    currentChatId = document.getElementById('currentChat').getAttribute('mail');
    myToken = JSON.parse(window.localStorage._connectData).aimsid; /*session token*/
    
    
    var encodifyText = function(txt){
        var temp = [];
        var returnVal = '';
        temp = txt.split('\n');
        for (i=0; i<temp.length; i++){
            returnVal += encodeURIComponent(txt.split('\n')[i]) + '%0A';
        }
        return returnVal.slice(0,-3); /*Delete last newline*/
    };
    
    
    var changeMessageFunc = async function(){
        const response = await fetch('https://needed.site/api/sendIM', {
            'headers': {
                'accept': '*/*',
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
                'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
                'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site'
            },
            'referrer': 'https://needed.site/',
            'referrerPolicy': 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
            'body': 't=' +encodeURIComponent(currentChatId)+ '&message=' +encodifyText(textToInsert)+ '&updateMsgId=' +msgIdInChange+ '&f=json&aimsid=' +encodeURIComponent(myToken),
            'method': 'POST',
            'mode': 'cors',
            'credentials': 'omit'
        });
    };
    
    await changeMessageFunc();
})();
```

The problem is that new lines of the message in API-call are written like `%0A`. But this `%0A` breaks the bookmarklet, putting some of its code to the second line.

**Addition**: I've tried replacing `%A0` with `%25A0` which works in the bookmarklet, but fails in the browswer console. Moreover, sometimes the code deletes two symbols at the end of the message. What shall I do to make it work everywhere?

Comment: You should URL-encode your entire bookmarklet code

Comment: I don't understand - Why are you thanking yourself for your own self-answer?

Comment: @Bergi, Is it really worth to encode the whole bookmarklet code? Taking into account that it might complicate debugging and improving the bookmarklet?

Comment: @ZolVas the whole of the code is going to be added to the URL. If you don't encode all of it, then any time you might save, you then lose by having to know which *exact* part of the code needs to be encoded or not. And any change you make to the code you'd need to also encode manually. In reality what you should be doing is a *vastly* simpler workflow of only keeping one copy of the source and transforming it to a bookmarklet. Rather than try to maintain to concurrent copies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make it work both in the bookmarklet and the browser console, you could use `decodeURI('%250A')`:

```
    var encodifyText = function(txt){
        var temp = [];
        var returnVal = '';
        temp = txt.split('\n');
        for (i=0; i<temp.length; i++){
            returnVal += encodeURIComponent(txt.split('\n')[i]) + decodeURI('%250A');
        }
        return returnVal.slice(0, returnVal.lastIndexOf(decodeURI('%250A'))); /*Delete last newline*/
    };
```

Since `%25` doesn't break the bookmarklet, `decodeURI('%250A')` is supposed to work as `%0A`.

And in order to delete the last newline, instead of `returnVal.slice(0,-3)`, it might be better to use `returnVal.slice(0, returnVal.lastIndexOf(decodeURI('%250A')))`.

Comment: And why are you telling yourself that you hope it helps?  It seems like you would know if it helped or not before you posted it!